# Undefined index error while key exists in array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm pulling my hair on a proble which seems very simple, but I can't find a solution.

I have a simple `$row` array here :

```
array:2 [▼
  "reference" => "ABCDEF"
  "quantity" => "10"
]
```

I'm trying to parse it and retrieve quantities per reference using :

```
$line = [
  'ref' => strtoupper($row["reference"]),
  'quantity' => $row["quantity"]
];
```

I'm looping through array of lines using this code:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {               
  $line = [
    'ref' => strtoupper($row['reference']),
    'quantity' => $row['quantity']
  ];
}
```

As a test, my main array `$rows` has 2 lines :

```
^ array:3 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "ABCDEF"
    1 => "10"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "WXCVBN"
    1 => "3"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    0 => null
  ]
]
```

However, I'm getting the following error :

```
Undefined index: reference
```

Strangely enough, if I comment out the

```
'ref' => strtoupper($row["reference"]),
```

line, I can get the "quantity" value with no issue...

I know the key is in there, since the debug of the `$row` object gives the above result.

It must be dead simple... but I can't find the solution...

If anyone could please help ?

Comment: Did you get quantity normally or have same issue with it?

Comment: Quantity wont work because the error is already triggered the row before. What is the output if you dd($row);

Comment: maybe you are trying to access $row before it even exist. If there was more code about from where you are getting that row and on which position you are calling $row['reference'] then we might be able to help

Comment: @Collin : the dd($row) gives :

^ array:2 [▼
  "reference" => "KKT"
  "quantity" => "10"
]

Comment: I believe the $row exists, since I can dd it.

Comment: Do you have quantity if you remove row with ref or you get same error?

Comment: please put here your php code so i find soluation

Comment: my code is in the original question text.

Comment: @Andery Yerokhin 
Strangely enough, if I comment the 
```'ref' => strtoupper($row["reference"]),``` 
line, I can get the "quantity" value with no issue... Updating my main question with this info.

Comment: Can you append new member to array ie.: $row["reference"] = 'TEST'; and then do dd($row) What is output in this case?

Comment: is the row array of your example a litteral row of a bigger array?

Comment: @Collin : yes, it's the result of the foreach when I'm looping through the main array. However the problem happens right from the first row. Other rows are not parsed since the error happens straight away.

Comment: Maybe should have told that :) , can you show the foreach? (Add it to the question)

Comment: @Collin: just added to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the $row variable a row from a bigger array that is used in a foreach loop.
This might be the solution to your problem.

```
$array = [
  [ "reference" => "ABC", "quantity" => "10"],
  [ "reference" => "ABC", "quantity" => "10"],
  [ "reference" => "ABC", "quantity" => "10"],
];

$line[] = '';

foreach($array as $row)
{
    $line['ref'] = $row['reference'];
    $line['quantity'] = $row['quantity'];
}
```

In this example $array is your bigger array, i use it to test the example.
After that i create a empty array $line to append the "new" data.

Could you try this?

Edit:

After taking a look at your loop and the array i noticed that your array doesnt have a reference key. Can you try `strtoupper(row[0])`?

Comment: Just tested. It makes no difference :(

Comment: if I try `strtoupper(row[0])` , I get :
`Undefined offset: 0`

It's like I can't get to the first column... weird... This code has worked before...

Comment: Drop the output please

Comment: So apparently there's a key, can you acces the $row['reference'] if you dont use the strtoupper function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215363/discussion-between-collin-and-adam-dulson).

Answer (score 0):

Viewing your code seems that you convert `$row` array to `$line` without rewrite key in new array.

**your code**

```php
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $line = [
            'ref' => strtoupper($row['reference']),
            'quantity' => $row['quantity']
        ];
    }
```

With your rewrite you can access `$line` data by index, not by key

```php
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "ABCDEF"
    1 => "10"
  ]
  ...
]
```

**My solution**

If you want to access your `$line` data by key, you need to rewrite your loop as:

```php
foreach($rows as $rowData) {
    foreach($rowData as $rowKey => $rowValue) {
        $data = [
            'ref' => $rowKey => strtoupper$($rowValue),
            'quantity' => $row['quantity']
        ];
    }
    $line[] = $data;
}
```